# Set UIView position in portrait and landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have create a loader view.I have set the position of the indicator with the following code :

```
    loadingView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(455, 225, 80, 80)]
```

How can I set a different position for the portrait mode ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
//portrait
loadingView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225, 455, 80, 80)];//any position you want
}
else
{
//landscape
loadingView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(455, 225, 80, 80)];//any position you want
}
```